# Sprite light blur around separate sprites

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am creating my first game on Unity, and I sliced a sprite sheet that I made. However, when I put the sliced sprites into my scene, both the scene and game view shows a white fuzzy outline.

[image: An example of the outline]

I have looked online for help, but all of the articles I have looked at talk about Unity adds lots of anti-aliasing, which makes the sprite blurry. But my sprites aren't blurry.

[image: This is a picture of my settings for the sprite sheet]

Any tips would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Is the white fuzzy outline present in the sprite's underlying texture? If you drew the texture against a white background in a paint program that tries to smooth out the colors (anti-aliasing), that might leave you with that sort of outline.

Comment: No, I used procreate on my iPad. I made sure the background was on a separate layer, and before I imported the sheet I removed the background layer. So there should be no way for the fuzziness to be there. Plus, I don't see the fuzziness in Photoshop or any other program. Just in Unity.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming. Unfortunately I am not super familiar with Unity's sprite engine, but I do hope you find a solution!